# i'm trying to check a string belongs to which text file

Tags: string, if-statement, for-loop, blogs

I'm trying to scrape a blog's comments and decide whether it is emotional and informational.

I found out the most frequently used nouns (top 10).

After that process, I made two txt files.

First file contains emotional nouns. Second file contains informational nouns.

Finally, I want to know whether a blog has more emotional nouns or more informational nouns. Which codes do I need to make for the last process?

Comment: How large is the file? If the file is small and can be handled easily, you can just import the two files as dictionaries and write for loops in python with counters, if the word from the dictionary, increase the counter. Which ever counter is higher, thats what the blog contains more

Comment: Could you show me rough code? please..TT

Comment: have you **tried anything yourself** yet? SO is not a free coding service, you know?

Comment: Have you tried COUNTING the nouns in each file as you insert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# This is the file where you have your top 10 nouns
fc = open("words.txt")
list_blog = []
for line in fc:
    list_blog.append(line.strip())

f1 = open("file1.txt") # This is your first file of emotional nouns
d1 = {}
c = 0
for line in fc:
    c+=1
    d1[line] = str(c)

f2 = open("file2.txt") # This is your seconf file of informational nouns
d2 = {}
c = 0
for line in fc:
    c+=1
    d2[line] = str(c)

count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0

for i in list_blog:
    if i in d1:
        count1+=1
    elif i in d2:
        count2+=1
    else:
        count3+=1

print(count1,count2,count3)
```

There could be a better way to write it, but I just wrote it quickly so its not the most efficient code